# Connecting to a SQL Server or MySQL database with Windows CE 6.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, pocketpc

I've been having issues trying to connect mySQL Server MC9190 (barcode scanner) to a SQL Server database and I've been having issues. It works fine when I run on my desktop, but when I try to run it on my pocket PC that runs on Windows CE 6.0 it throws the error:

> System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
>   Message="File or assembly name 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=3.0.3600.0,Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=3BE235DF1C8D2AD3', or one of its dependencies, was not found."

Anyone have any idea how to connect my pocket pc to the database so I can input the data I collect from the scanner into the database? Here is my code when I'm trying to connect to the database:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=*****\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=testing;Trusted_Connection=yes;connection timeout=15;user id=************");

try
{
            //open the server
            myConnection.Open();
            //Insert values passed into the metod
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (Part_Number, total, number_of_packs, dunsNumber, serialNumber, truck_number) VALUES (@Part_Number,@total,@number_of_packs,@dunsNumber,@serialNumber,@truck_number)", myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Part_Number", partNumber);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number_of_packs", numOfPacks);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dunsNumber", dunsNumber);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serialNumber", serialNumber);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@truck_number", laneNumber);

            //execute the query
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: what version of System.Data.SqlClient is installed on the Pocket PC?

Comment: @ChrisBint the version that is referenced in my program is 3.0.3600.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot use Express on it.  You will need to use Compact.

Here is a tutorial on setting up SQL CE with C# Apps.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlce

Here are the install instructions for CE 6  (MS SQL Compact needs an extra install).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13kw2t64(v=vs.90).aspx

Edit: --> this is assuming you are trying to use a database on the machine itself.  Otherwise this won't be your answer.